# How to manage entities in Redux/ngrx state?

Tags: redux, ngrx, state-management

We have been using `ngrx` for state management in our application. As `ngrx` and `redux` follow the same principles of state management, this question applies to both.

For state management, we have been using `normalizr` library to normalize any incoming data from the server. We have the following issue as to how to share `entities` across different state slices. For eg.,

```
// app state
{
  sliceA: sliceAState, // corresponds to feature module A, handled by reducerA
  sliceA: sliceBState, // corresponds feature module B, handled by reducerB
}
```

Both sliceA and sliceB contain a `list` of specific entity called `location`. Now what is the correct approach here

- Maintain `location` entity in both state slices - possibly in the future some other state slice might also need the same entity.
- Maintain the `same state slice` but this would require cross referencing across modules - also note that we use lazy loading to load different feature modules.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maintain the same state slice but this would require cross referencing across modules - also note that we use lazy loading to load different feature modules.

This is going to be your best bet in order to adhere to the principles of a [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth).

If you start maintaining the same data in multiple locations you will need to update multiple data sources every time the data changes. If there is only a single source of truth, you remove the chance of inconsistencies in your store.